# covariant types in function pointers

Tags: c++

Why is is wrong to cast function like in example below?
Covariant types are supposed to work like this aren't they?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{};
struct B : public A{};

typedef A*(*func)();

B* b() { std::cout << "b"; return new B; }
A* a() { std::cout << "a"; return new A; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    func fa = a;
    fa();

//  I can't do this
//  func fb = b;
//  fb();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covariant types are supported only in return types of `virtual` member functions of classes. They are not supported in global functions.

```
struct A
{
   virtual A* copy() {return new A();}
};

struct B : public A
{
   virtual B* copy() {return new B();}
};

void foo()
{
   B b;
   A* ap = b.copy(); // OK
   B* bp = b.copy(); // OK
   A* ap2 = ap->copy(); // OK
   B* bp2 = ap->copy(); // NOT OK
}
```

You can use the work around suggested by "Cheers and thl. = Alf" for global functions.

Answer (score 2):

It's just not supported, even though it makes sense.

In C++11 you can easily define a wrapper on the spot:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{};
struct B : public A{};

typedef A*(*func)();

B* b() { std::cout << "b"; return new B; }
A* a() { std::cout << "a"; return new A; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    func fa = a;
    fa();

    func fb = []() -> A* { return b(); };
    fb();
}
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need (make it work without changing `func` declaration). Just side note, works with VS2013 but not in VS2010

Comment: even though you answer is what I need, it is not what I asked, so I have to accept other answer, sorry for that and once again, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `std::function` rather than a function pointer:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct A{};
struct B : public A{};

using func = std::function<A*()>;

A* a() {std::cout << "a"; return new A;}
B* b() {std::cout << "b"; return new B;}

int main() {
    func fa = a;
    fa();

    func fb = b;
    fb();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbcb4493f114c5b9)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know about std::function, unfortunately I can't use it, because function typedef is on the library side of my code, which I cannot modify. but your solution is of course correct

Answer (score 0):

That's something known as typecasting. Not every `A` is a `B`, so the compiler can't do that conversion automatically. Consider this case:

```
struct A {};
struct B : public A {};
struct C : public A {};

A* a = new A; //OK
a = new B; // B is derived from A, valid
a = new C; // C is also derived from A, valid

B* b = new B; // OK
b = new C; // error, B is not derived from C 
b = new A; // error, B might have some members that A does not have
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I think you are showing the wrong thing. You are casting "down" (A->B) so obviously `not every A is B`. But I am casting "up" (B->A) since `every B is A`.